# How to write an ArrayList to file and retrieve it?

Tags: android

now im trying to use this

```
FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput("CalEvents", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(returnlist);
    oos.close();
```

in order to save "returnlist" which is an ArrayList to the file "CalEvents"
now my question is , is that the right way to do it?
and how do i retrieve the list back?

thanks in advance

Comment: To get back Use ObjectInputStream().readObject(); and check instance of ArrayList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
    fis = openFileInput("CalEvents");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Object> returnlist = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:** Can be simplified:

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
    fis = openFileInput("CalEvents");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Object> returnlist = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Assuming that you are in a class which extends `Context` (like `Activity`). If not, then you will have to call the `openFileInput()` method on an object which extends `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to write your Arraylist in a file

```
public static void write(Context context, Object nameOfClass) {
    File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + "serlization");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    String filename = "MessgeScreenList.srl";
    ObjectOutput out = null;

    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directory
                + File.separator + filename));
        out.writeObject(nameOfClass);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Complete example here, with Read method](https://gagandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/read-or-write-serializable-arraylist.html)

Comment: The link mentioned doesn't work! Could you please update your comment?