# Java - Saving an ArrayList on resets

Tags: java, arraylist, save

I am currently trying to make a plugin, however I am having a bit of an issue.
What I am trying to do, is save an ArrayList, when the program exits and restarts.
The type of plugin I am making is for Minecraft, and I was just wondering if anyone could help:

public class KitPvP extends JavaPlugin {

```
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
public static KitPvP plugin;

public ArrayList<String> CoolDown = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> NauseaShooter = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> CupidLaunch = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> Assassin = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    this.logger.info("[Disenchant] Has been Disabled!");


}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    this.logger.info("[Disenchant] Has been Disabled!");
    new PlayerDeathEventListener(this);
    new PlayerInteractEventListener(this);
}
```

As usual the formatting is correct in eclipse, but not on here.

What I want to do, is save the Arraylist CoolDown, so when it disables it saves into a text file, and when it reenables, it loads the text file onto the ArrayList,

Thanks for all the help

- REDANDBLUEWHO

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743195/how-to-save-an-arraylist-to-file

Answer (score 0):

You could use object serialization with [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and a Shutdown Hook. However the elements stored in the array list must implement Serializable.