# Saving to SD card and displaying on ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, save

So I'm trying to have a TextInput from a EditText to save whats written there with a button (save) to save into the SD card and also be displayed on the ListView. Just doesn't work, do not get any errors.

**The Code I Use: (Sorry that its a lot)**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});


try{   
String TextInput = mTextInput.getText().toString();
if(!TextInput.trim().equals("")){
    File file =new File("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html");

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(TextInput);
        bufferWritter.close();
} 
}catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

public void onCreate() {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html");
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Clicking on items
         }
    });
}
private ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Any thought how to make this work?

Comment: Your code seems a little confusing. Can you verify that the code is correct? Look at the code, the GetFiles just returns null so you will never have anything in the list.

Comment: Seems to be correct, I have mostly followed guides and tutorials I'm new to coding overall so I have probably missed something really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I moved some of your code around. First, you need to attach the R.id.save listener when you create the view. I moved it to the create and I have it calling the save.  You also need to write the getfiles functionality to read the files. Currently you have nothing coded when means your list will never populate.

```
        public void save() {
            try{
                String TextInput = mTextInput.getText().toString();
                if(!TextInput.trim().equals("")){
                    File file =new File("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html");

                    if(!file.exists()){
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
                    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
                    bufferWritter.write(TextInput);
                    bufferWritter.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace(); }

        }

        public void onCreate() {

            ListView lv;
            ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html");
            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // Clicking on items
                }
            });

            findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    save();
                }
            });
        }
        private ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String string) {
            //TODO you need to read files and return a list of strings for this to work.
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but,
`public void save {` I get an error "void is an invalid type for the variable save" 

And on, `public void onClick(View v) { save(); }` I can either "Create methods 'save()'" or
Create method in 'save()' in type 'MainActivity' Witch one?

And how do I solve the first error?

Comment: Makes since solved it, now you said I returned Null. What do I write their instead to make it work?

Comment: You will have to figure out that for the most part. I don't know what exactly your trying to do. If your trying to save a list, I would suggest saving it as json and then reading it as json. You will need to do some research on how to do this, there are a lot of guides out there to help. Here is decently easy tut to follow. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

Comment: Don't understand the tutorial and don't understand how it will help me. What I want to do is: Have an TextInput you write something for example "Potato", you press a button and that information/potato text will be saved to the SD card. And also displayed on a ListView that takes the "list/items/potato" that takes its information or know what to put on the list from the SD card. So you will end up with a long list, example: potato, tomato, mouse, etc.

Comment: Well you have to save the list in some sort of format. I recommend json because its scales well if you get into doing web services. You can save the text as comma delimitted or each line if you prefer. Either way you need to save the list items so you can retrieve it later. I am not going to write the entire code for you, you need to take some time and research how to do some of the things. Another link is the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158483/how-to-write-an-arraylist-to-file-and-retrieve-it