# android - How to retrieve MPAndroidChart ArrayList from file

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mpandroidchart

I'm using **MPAndroidChart** in my app and I'd like to save an `ArrayList` in a file, for later use.
Here is where I save it to a file in the internal storage:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.entries_key));

// Save chart data
FileOutputStream out;
try {
  out = openFileOutput("listFile", MODE_PRIVATE);

  ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
  outputStream.writeObject(entries);
  outputStream.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
  try {

    if (out != null) {
      out.close();
    }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

And here is where I try to retrieve it, but the returned `ArrayList` doesn't contain any data and the default text ("No chart data available") in my `LineChart`:

```
File listFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "listFile");

if(listFile.exists()) {

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {

        inputStream = openFileInput("listFile");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

        // This line is evil
        ArrayList <Entry> entries = (ArrayList<Entry>) objectInputStream.readObject();

        // Set chart properties
        chart = ChartUtils.setChartProperties(chart);

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = ChartUtils.createSet(ChartViewer.this, entries);

        LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSet);
        chart.setData(data);

        // Let the chart knows data has changed
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chart.invalidate();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've doubled check it and I'm sure I'm reading in the correct file so the problem must be this line

`ArrayList <Entry> entries = (ArrayList<Entry>) objectInputStream.readObject();`

I found this way of reading ArrayList from file here [How to write an ArrayList to file and retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158483/how-to-write-an-arraylist-to-file-and-retrieve-it)

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in an hacky way.. I created a custom `MyEntry` class that implements `Serializable`

```
public class MyEntry implements Serializable {

   private float x;
   private float y;

   public MyEntry(float x, float y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }

   public MyEntry(){

   }

   public float getX() {
       return x;
   }

   public float getY() {
       return y;
   }

   public void setX(float x) {
       this.x = x;
   }

   public void setY(float y) {
       this.y = y;
   }
}
```

Than, when I need to save the data I get them from the `ArrayList<Entry>` and store them in an `ArrayList<MyEntry>`

```
// Save chart data
FileOutputStream out = null;

out = openFileOutput(recordName, MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
ArrayList<MyEntry> myEntries = new ArrayList<>();

for (int k = 0; k < entries.size(); k++) {
  Entry currentEntry = entries.get(k);
  MyEntry currentMyEntry = new MyEntry();
  currentMyEntry.setX(currentEntry.getX());
  currentMyEntry.setY(currentEntry.getY());
  myEntries.add(currentMyEntry);
}

outputStream.writeObject(myEntries);
outputStream.close();
```

And when I need to read the values back I take them from `MyEntry` object and put in an `Entry` object

```
FileInputStream inputStream;

inputStream = openFileInput(fileListName);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

ArrayList <MyEntry> myEntries = (ArrayList<MyEntry>) objectInputStream.readObject();
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < myEntries.size(); i++) {
  MyEntry currentMyEntry = myEntries.get(i);
  Entry currentEntry = new Entry();
  currentEntry.setX(currentMyEntry.getX());
  currentEntry.setY(currentMyEntry.getY());
  entries.add(currentEntry);
}

// Set chart properties
chart = ChartUtils.setChartProperties(chart);

LineDataSet lineDataSet = ChartUtils.createSet(ChartViewer.this, entries);

LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSet);
chart.setData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [ObjectOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream) says:

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams

The `ArrayList` implements the `Serializable` interface, but it refers to the `Entry` class which doesn’t. So, `Entry` objects are not serialized, (i.e., not saved or restored).

Comment: Here it seems that the Entry class implements Serializable https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/2797/commits/1b3b375ab3fef0eac419951ef394bf5196871228

Comment: this pull request not yet approved/merged into the master (or other production)